# Passing object to knockout component loaded via require

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I've just started looking at knockout components.

I am trying to do the following.

from the main module

```
var setup = {color:"pink"};
ko.components.register('headerbar', {require:"/headerbar"});
```

the component

```
define(["ko", "text!./headerbar.html"], function(ko, html) {
"use strict";

var vm = function(prms){
      //use passed setup info here  

};

return { viewModel: vm, template: html };
});
```

I hope to be able to do this, so I can pass in some set up details and not have to express them in each instance of the component via its params

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with.

```
    var ctxPassingLoader = {
        to_pass: {

        },
        loadComponent:function(name, cfg, callback){
            if(cfg.ctx){
                this.to_pass[name] = cfg.ctx;
            }
            app.ko.components.defaultLoader.loadComponent(name, cfg, callback);
        },
        loadViewModel: function(name, original, callback) {
            var ctx = this.to_pass[name] || original.ctx;
            this.to_pass[name] = null;
            if (ctx) {
                var wrapper;
                if(original.createViewModel){
                    wrapper = {
                        createViewModel : function(params, info){
                            original.createViewModel(params, info, ctx);
                        }
                    };
                }else{
                    wrapper = function(params){
                        return original(params, ctx);
                    };
                }
                app.ko.components.defaultLoader.loadViewModel(name, wrapper, callback);


            } else {
                callback(null);
            }
        }
    };
    app.ko.components.loaders.unshift(ctxPassingLoader);
```

calling code

```
var setup = {color:"pink"};
ko.components.register('headerbar', {require:"/headerbar", ctx:setup});
```

Comment: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-loaders.html#registering-custom-component-loaders